# how to use a base class pointer refer to a derived class member?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class a{};
class b : public class a{
public:
int c;
};
a* var = new b;
var->c=2;
```

Last line is not correct. Is it possible to refer to the derived class member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while var is a b object at compile time the compiler does not know that so you have to cast it to a b object or pointer like this.

```
(*(b*)var).c = 2;
((b*)var)->c = 2;
```

My computer science teacher explained that treat two cases when doing polymorphism run-time and compile time

Hope this helps.

Comment: `((b)*var).c = 2;` is not working. But `((b*)var)->c = 2;` is okay.

Comment: Sorry about the first one I might have screwed up the order of operations

Answer (score 1):

If the member is not in the base class, you should not be allowed to access it and it should give a compilation error. To access a member of derived class, you can typecast it to the derived class.

```
class a{};
class b : public class a{
public:
    int c;
};
a* var = new b;
((b*)var)->c=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) to downcast from Base to Derived and then access the member.

`static_cast<b*>(var)->c = 2;`